# Why is Jenkins terminating JVM after IE test?

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins

I have a maven project (java 1.8) where I run my selenium tests in IE.
Yesterday I upgraded all plugins and Jenkins.

As soon as I run my first test, it opens the IE browser and run the tests. Just after the test then I receive this error:

[image]

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Sorry for adding screenshot, will in future copy it from the console. Thanks for having a look

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this only worked temporary, now I still have the problem

I had to add this line "java -Xrs -Xmx256m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar" in my startjenkins.bat File. It is working after that and Jenkins isn't closing the JVM anymore

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins" 
java -Xrs -Xmx256m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar
java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8082
```